# Log properties: Cancellation property (visual intuition)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Disclaimer: I'm new to logs.

I understand the first part of the cancellation property in yellow below. Can anyone explain the second part? I'm confused how you can rewrite it without the a base.

[image]

Comment: hint: $a^? = x$ and $?=\log_a x$ mean the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

I think I figured this out. It comes from the definition of the inverse of an exponential function:

[image]

Comment: +1 for answering your own question. But it did take you just 13 minutes - you probably could have done it without posting here!

Comment: Agreed. I'll take it down if nobody finds it useful.

Answer (score 0):

yes it is right .
You can change the position of  a and x in second equation so it becomes $x^{log_a^a}$ but $log_a^a$ is 1 so $ x^1 $ =x . Hope this answer helps you understand this property.